# Setting 2-dimensional array into input hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which I have another to push into in a loop

```
array1[ [box1, type1, 10], [box1, type2, 12] ]
array2[ [box2, type1, 10], [box2, type2, 12], [box2, type2, 12] ]

var curArray = new Array();
```

so in a loop:

```
var testarray = new Array('box1', 'type1', 10);
curArray.push(testarray);
```

and I have to post it so I set it in a hidden field. 
array.push works when I console.log(curArray) but if you set it to a hidden field by

```
$('hdnField').val(curArray)
```

it no longer become a multidimensional array.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: is this an ajax post? if so can add data within ajax code and not need hidden field

Comment: hi @charlietfl, thanks for the reply. nope it's a form post

Comment: then answer below to parse to json is best way, decode the json at server if need to work with array there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$('hdnField').val(JSON.stringify(curArray));
```

Comment: hi there, it turns it into a string, then I will decode it in the server?

Comment: YES, you can find easily a JSON Parser library in your server language

Answer (score 1):

You can try JSON.stringify()

```
$('hdnField').val(JSON.stringify(curArray));
```

Does this work?

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work. having a weird error "Unexpected token b". i'm sure they wasn't any extra syntax that i mistyped.

Comment: it's not parse but stringify. like $('#hdnField').val(JSON.stringify(curArray));